# Еще о корне "яр"

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Во-первых, большое спасибо за интересный и обстоятельный ответ на вопрос об именах языческих богов. Но меня заинтересовало вот что: почему, если корень "яр" означает "белый" или "весна", есть слова "ярость", "яриться" с, если не противоположным, то совершенно другим значением?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ЯРОСТЬ

Происходит от прил. ярый, из праслав. формы *jarъ, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. ꙗръ, ст.-слав ꙗръ (αὐστηρός), русск. ярый, яркий, укр. ярий, болг. я́рост «ярость», сербохорв. jа̏ра «жар от печи», jа́рити се «горячиться», словенск. járǝn «яростный, энергичный, сильный», др.-чешск. jarobujný «горячий, ярый», словацк. jarý «свежий», польск. jarzyć «ожесточать», в.-луж. jara «очень», jěrу «горький», н.-луж. jěrу «терпкий, горький, вспыльчивый, грубый». Сюда же относится болг. яра́ «блеск, зарево», польск. jarzyć się «сиять, сверкать», za-jarzyć «засиять», также имена Ярослав, Яромер и др. Праслав. *jarъ родственно греч. ζωρός «огненный, сильный, несмешанный (о вине)», у Гесихия: ἐνεργής, ταχύς, атт. εὔζωρος «чистый (о вине)», ἐπιζαρέω «набрасываюсь, притесняю». Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.

Могу предположить, что *весна* - яркое время года, как и *белый* - один из самых таких бросающихся в глаза цветов. Для сравнения - *яровые* культуры, т.е. те культуры, которые сеют весной (в отличие от *озимых*)

Answer (score 0):

А откуда там "белый"?
Остальное все довольно логично. Весна - дружные (яростные) всходы, яровые (весенние) посевы. Отсюда же и сама ярость, переходящая на "сияние", "огонь".

Answer (score 0):

Языковедам известны случаи, когда слово в процессе семантической эволюции приобретало противоположный смысл. Здесь возможна такая семантическая цепочка: сильный, очень, крепкий, насыщенный, крутой, чистый, белый.

Answer (score -1):

Все слова, производные от слова ЯР, берут свой исток от влияния Солнца на окружающий мир или находятся в сравнении с его свойствами, или, как в именах собственных, ЯР добавляется впереди, в виде украшения слова.
Кроме того культ Яра -это культ весеннего Солнца, первого животворящего тепла.
Или, в переносном значении молодого, возрождающегося Солнца.
Итак:
Ярый - это горячий;
Ярмо - то, что выжгли;
Яровой - весенний;
Яриться - горячиться;
Но ЯР, в смысле обрыв -татарское яруга, не входит в этот ряд.
Итак, во многих словах обыгрывается жар  или тепло, которое несёт весенне Солнце;
Второе направление - пробуждение к жизни и чувствам природы, зверей и человека;
Третье - свойства душевного состояния возбуждённого к деятельности человека;
И, естественно, главное, Ярый - это ещё и светящийся, отсюда яркий, а яркий - это и блестящий, и ослепительный, но белый ли? (последнее, пожалуй, не совсем достоверно).
Есть убедительная версия:  ярина - церковная овечья шерсть, от ягнёнка ярки (до года)- чисто белого цвета( "Аки ярина белая"), (который приносился в жертву), потому ярина - белая.
Почему ягнёнок-ярка? Да всё просто. Новый год на Руси начинался 1 марта – с началом весенних работ на полях. Или с приходом Ярилы. Новый год - это приход Ярилы! (Только не Дедушки Мороза, как придумано сейчас, а возрождение Бога Солнца, главного Бога у древних славян! По аналогии с современностью, Ярило Солнце - это, как Новый год - мальчик). Потому один год - это один ярка, а следующий это уже больше.
Самое явное понимание, почему ЯР белый, вытекает их названия первого месяца весны, русское название - БЕЛОЯР, это наш март, мир ещё белый от снега, но пришёл Яр. 
Бог Яр пришёл в белый мир снега!